# Transition width on mouseout for pseudo before element

Tags: css, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I have a before pseudo element that I am trying to transition the width of when another element is hovered over.

Link to jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc3r8thp/6/)

I seem to be able to transition the width on mouseover of the element, but on mouseleave I am unable to transition back to a width of 0px.

**EDIT**

I think I explained what I am trying to do the wrong way. See updated code and jsFiddle below. I have a parent item that when hovered over, I need the width of the :before element of the child to transition.

```
<div class="hover">
   <div class="transition"></div>
</div>

.hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
}      

.transition:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 top: -10px;
 right: 100%;
 background-color: #d3d;
 z-index: -1;
 -webkit-transition: width 2s;
 transition: width 2s;
}

.hover:hover .transition:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 125px;
 height: 70px;
 top: -10px;
 right: 94%;
 background-color: #d3d;
 -webkit-transition: width 2s;
 transition: width 2s;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the single colon syntax for `before` and `after` pseudo elements is considered obsolete (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore)

Comment: What exactly is the outcome you are trying to achieve?  There's a lot of weird positioning in your CSS that seems to only be relevant for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was mostly a matter of positioning. The width was actually animating, but the positioning of the element on hover was removing it from the viewport.

In order to absolutely position an element within the context of its parent, the parent must be positioned. Using `position: relative` is a quick and easy way to make this happen but otherwise keep an element the same. Also, if you only want the width to change on hover, only change the width.

I'm still not sure what your goal is with this, but my snippet should mostly reproduce the design you had implemented with the animation showing both on and off hover.

```css
.hover { display: inline-block; }

.transition {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.transition::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 70px;
    top: -10px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #d3d;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
}

.hover:hover > .transition::before { width: 125px; }
```

```html
<div class="hover">
   <div class="transition"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. Appreciate the feedback! I updated my explanation a bit because I think I explained it wrong. Will this still work if the hover on the parent element is what needs to trigger the transition for the child?

Comment: Yes, it should. I'll update the code to reflect your changes

Comment: @KyleGiard-Chase: Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I optimize and change your css. I hope it can help you. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/Lc3r8thp/3/)

```css
.transition {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
}      

.transition:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #d3d;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: 2s;
}

.transition:hover:before {
  width: 125px;
  height: 70px;
    transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="transition"></div>
```